# Can't get array from JS to my Spring boot controller?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am having a little problem while sending data from my React app to my Spring Boot Controller, I am sending the data via a put method, but I get 400, error, and an error in eclipse pops up, so What I did is :

```
export const changeContratTypes = (idContrat, items, declaration) => {
    const endpoint = template(CONTRAT_TYPES_CHANGE);
    return instance // just an axios instance
      .put(endpoint({ idContrat }), { items, declaration })
      .then(values => values)
      .catch(err => err.response);
};
```

My endpoint constant is the url, simple is that, and I send declaration which is an integer and items which is an array of object, my object structure is :

```
{ 
   id: 1, // or 2, 3, ....
   isSelected: true, // or false
   title: "a String here"       
}
```

To get this in Spring boot I created this method in my controller :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@ApiOperation(value = "${contrat.recuperation}", notes = "${contrat.recuperation.notes}", response = ContratDetailDto.class)
@PutMapping(value="/{idContrat}/trtype")
@ApiModelProperty(example = "4000004")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Enrigistrer Les types de contrats ") })
public ResponseEntity enrigistrerTypesDeContrat(@ApiParam(value = "${contrat.recuperation.param.id}") @PathVariable long idContrat, @RequestBody TypesConformites tcf) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("appel de la méthode enrigistrerTypesDeContrat");
    }

    System.out.println("Voila "+tcf.getDeclaration());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This controller is well mapped and other methods in it works fine, but all methods I used are Get Methods.

What I did before that is creating a class used as a RequestBody :

```
@Getter @Setter
public class TypesConformites {

   private int declaration;
   private ArrayList<Item> items; 

   public TypesConformites() {
   }

}
```

and Here is my Item class :

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Item {
   private int id;
   private String title;
   private boolean isSelected;

   public Item() {
   }
}
```

I get this error in Java :

> Blockquote
>
> JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "isSelected" (class com.apicil.cosy.contrat.controller.api.impl.external.Item), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "isSelected" (class com.apicil.cosy.contrat.controller.api.impl.external.Item), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "title", "id", "selected"])
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 66] (through reference chain: com.apicil.cosy.contrat.controller.api.impl.external.TypesConformites["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.apicil.cosy.contrat.controller.api.impl.external.Item["isSelected"])

What's wrong with that code, Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error states you are passing "isSelected" it should just be called "selected" according to your defined service.

Comment: can you rewrite this as answer so I can mark it as true .. thanks it worked

Comment: This is the weird issue i also faced . just changed the boolean variable name to "Selected" and also in the request body and classes

Comment: I changed it in Front, my field name was isSelected and now it is selected.

Comment: @TaouBen see the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the **Item** is deserialised by jackson like this :-

```
public void setId(String firstName) {

public void setTitle(String lastName) {

public void setSelected(boolean isActive) {
```

To avoid this you can just changed the mapping name in the **Item** and request body.. or annotated your isSelected with `@JsonProperty`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I solved my problem by changing things in the Front not the back